# Avoid Overriding method from library

Tags: c++

I want to have the same name has the method from the C++ library cmath in a class method but without overriding it by my own method. I know I could just change the name but that is not what I want to do. Is this possible ?

calculator.cpp:

```
#include <calculator.h>
#include <cmath>

int Calculator::pow(int entier, int puissance) {
     return pow(entier, puissance);
}
```

calculator.h:

```
class Calculator {
public:
      Calculator() {}
      int pow (int a, int b);
};
```

I already know that the types I am using are wrong for this type of computation but that is not the point.

Comment: Just use [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)? Here `cmath` is dragging you down. There's also `::pow` as an option, but that's getting silly.

Comment: @AllanWind `cmath` doesn't do namespaces. It's the C functions.

Comment: I don't get the question, I guess.  If op wants to create a function with the same name, then use a namespace for the new function to avoid a conflict.  It should at least be class method.  Oh... maybe op means in the int Calculator::pow().  Use ::pow(..) or std::pow as @tadman said above.

Comment: @tadman — `<cmath>` puts the names of the C library math functions in `std`. It is also allowed to put them in the global namespace.

Comment: @PeteBecker Does it also do that? You don't need a prefix to use them, and there's no `using namespace std` forced on you.

Comment: @tadman -- whoops, my summary was a little too brief. The standard **requires** the `<c...>` headers to put their names into `std::`, and it **allows** them to also put those names into the global namespace. That latter part is a compromise for implementability. The original requirement was `std::` only, but that's nasty to implement and maintain if the vendor doesn't also control the C headers. So every implementation I know of does both, and that's what you're seeing.

Comment: @PeteBecker That makes a lot more sense. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not overriding anything. Your `pow` function is in a different scope than `std::pow` (or the global `::pow`). The standard library `pow` is still there, unchanged by your definition.

It is just that unqualified name lookup will only find the functions with the name declared in the inner-most scope where a declaration for the name is found.

If that is not what you want, you need to qualify then name to let the compiler know which `pow` exactly you want to call, e.g.

```
 return std::pow(entier, puissance);
```

to call the `pow` function in the standard library namespace `std` or

```
 return ::pow(entier, puissance);
```

to call the `pow` function in the global namespace scope. However, including `<cmath>` does not guarantee that the standard library `pow` function will be declared in the global namespace scope, which is why you should use `std::pow` (instead of `::pow` or just `pow`) in any case anyway.